# How to not lose data while pausing and resuming papaparse streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, papaparse

I have a papaparse function for processing large (>5GB) tsvs.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Papa.parse<T>(this.file, {
        ...
        step: (result: ParseStepResult<T>, parser: Papa.Parser) => {
          this.batch.push(result.data);
          if (this.batchCondition(this.batch)) {
            this.file?.pause();
            parser.pause();
            this.saveData(this.batch).then(() => {
              this.batch = [];
              parser.resume();
              this.file?.resume();
            });
          }
        },
        complete: async () => {
          await this.saveData(this.batch);
          this.onCompletion();
          resolve();
        },
      });
    });
```

My issue is that I've found that I absolutely need to call `pause()` and `resume()` on *both* the file `ReadableStream` and the papaparse `Parser` objects, otherwise it ends up reading the entire file somehow and running out of memory.

However, between the consecutive pause and resume calls, data is always being lost somehow, since when I rerun on the same file a couple times, I get a non-zero number of new entries found to save.

Pausing the file ReadableStream first, and resuming it last, seems to lose less data than the doing so with the Parser first, but is still non-zero.

Is there an established pattern for this?

Comment: Did you ever solve your issue?

Comment: I have hit a similar issue and I think it's a bug in papaparse. I can reliably trigger errors using pause/resume in a step function